# Iso booting from dvd but not from usb

Tags: boot, bios, elementaryos

A tested working usb drive won't boot from my computer.
The same boots on my laptop. When I select to boot into the usb,
a blinking underscore persists. Nothing loads.
I have tried playing with the bios settings but in vain.
My bios version is : Intel Corp. RQG4110H.86A.0017.2011.0322.1.523
O.S. which i am trying to install: Elementary OS Freya.
..  I already have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 installed.
Please Help.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Try another (preferably older) USB disk. I ran into issues like that in the past, it seems the reason was the BIOS not recognizing some of the newer device IDs.

The other reason may be EFI/BIOS issues. Make you sure you use the right boot mode for your OS.

Comment: How to identify which is the right boot mode?

Comment: When I go into the boot options, the usb drive is shown. So probably it is not because the bios is not recognizing it. When i select it, this blinking underscore comes.

Comment: If you don't know the right boot modes supported by the OS (I know very little about *Elementary OS*, and so my comments are generic) try both EFI and BIOS (the latter sometimes named EFI + CSM) boot modes.